# How do I unflag something?

Tags: support

I flagged [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622275/ls-discrepancy-with-du-df-output) as off-topic as it was about some obscure distro, but it has since been edited into a general Linux question.

How do I remove the flag I raised? There doesn't seem to be any option that I can find.

Comment: Many people have suggested this feature many times but for some reason, but for some reason those who would have to implement it, don't want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You can't.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Don't worry too much. The odd invalid or disputed flag isn't that big a problem.